# Error: The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console

Tags: android, google-play-console, google-developers-console, google-play-developer-api

I completed In App Purchase for Android. Play API give me purchase token, package name and product id.

But i try verification API and then api give me error.

I create a new service account in Google Developer Console and i linked from API Access to Google Play Developer Console. I try the API (https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/inappproducts/get) but still same error:

The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue, and after lots of search we found laravel package to get subscription information.

Please find link :
https://github.com/imdhemy/laravel-in-app-purchases#purchase-events

You need to implement backend api to get subscribed plan information.